# Button active state offset via class

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons in a container. I would like their active state to offset down by 1px or so. Rather than write css for each button, I would rather class them and have their active state relative to their original position.

The css currently looks like below. Or check out [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HK5SV/). The problem is that the active state offset seems to be greater than 1px for the bottom 2x buttons. Not sure what I am missing.

```
#buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

.greenButtClass {
    font-family: 'avenirMedium';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 22pt;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #7ac144;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #7ac144;
}

.greenButtClass:hover {
    background-color: #6DA840;
}

.greenButtClass:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what i suggest if i understand right your problem:

**html:**

```
<div id='buttons'>
    <br>
    <button id='places' class='greenButtClass' style="top:15px">Button 1</button><br>
    <button id='nature' class='greenButtClass' style="top:105px">Button 2</button><br>
    <button id='trails' class='greenButtClass' style="top:205px">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#buttons{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px
}
.greenButtClass{
    font-family: 'avenirMedium';        
    z-index: 10;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 22pt;
    width:200px;    
    background-color:#7ac144;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius:35px;
    padding:8px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #7ac144;
}
.greenButtClass:hover {
    background-color:#6DA840;
}
.greenButtClass:active {
    position:relative;  
    top:1px;
}
```

And a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeLWw/1/)

And another one with more spaces between button as your example:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeLWw/3/)